# ssh Connection refused, stuck at "debug1: Local version string"

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to connect to my Redhat AWS instance with a port other than 22.

This command works: 
`ssh -i my.pem -p 22 ec2-user@X.X.X.X`

But this command does not:`ssh -i my.pem -p 8157 -vvv ec2-user@X.X.X.X`

The second command outputs:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to X.X.X.X port 8157.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file my.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file my.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
```

but then just hangs. On the server I'm trying to connect to, however, when I run `nc -l 8157` I can see

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
```

If I take out the `-vvv` part I just get a quick "Connection refused" error.

When I log into the machine and run `ssh -p 8157 -vvv ec2-user@localhost`

I get the following output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 8157
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 8157.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 8157: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 8157: Connection refused
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you opened up the firewall or changed the AWS security policies to allow access to that port?

Comment: If you login to the AWS system and then run `ssh ... ec2-user@localhost` , does that work?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Yes, I've opened up the security group on the instance. I've also checked the VPC flow logs and I can see my source and target IP and the 8157 port showing up as "ACCEPT OK", so I don't think it's an AWS firewall issue. Also, if the security group were the issue I wouldn't be able to establish a connect at all, right? The ssh verbose command says `Connection established`, so I think it's getting through, it's just not finishing.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick What could go in the `. . .`? I didn't know you could connect to localhost. I'm guessing I would just do `ssh -p 8157 ec2-user@localhost`?

Comment: Same command - `ssh -i my.pem -p 8157 -vvv ec2-user@localhost` . This will remove from consideration all (or all but one) firewalls.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I didn't want to copy the private key up to the server, so tried `ssh -p 8157 -vvv ec2-user@localhost` and that also led to a "Connection refused" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This command works: `ssh -i my.pem -p 22 ec2-user@X.X.X.X`
>
> But this command does not: `ssh -i my.pem -p 8157 -vvv ec2-user@X.X.X.X`

---

Your other side may have opened port in the firewall, but...

Since port 22 works, your server listens on that port.

Re-configure your server to listen on whatever port you wish.

---

You can do that in the file:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

With the following setting:

```
Port 8157
```

Don't forget to restart your SSH daemon afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean by "Re-configure your server to listen on whatever port you wish." Do you mean change the firewall? My AWS security groups (firewall) are completely open. Are you referring to the ssh daemon's ports? If so, how can I change that?

Comment: @user554481 Suffice that edit?

Comment: Wow, that worked! Is it not open to all ports by default?

Comment: @user554481 No, it is not..

Comment: My problem was, i  opened a dhcp sserver, set port to 2223. I was trying to connect to the dhcp port 2223 while my ssh was set on 2222. No wonder the server threw error when I tried to open it at 2222. Your answer helped me realize this. I had to say thank you LinuxSecurityFreak. Your answer showed a path to solving my problem. Thank you so much. I've been pulling my hair out until I got no more left trying to solve this question. Now it's regrowing thanks to your answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I figured out that the ssh deamon (sshd.service) turned off, on the local machine.
Check if this is the case:

```bash
sudo systemctl status sshd.service
```

if it return "inactive state":

```bash
sudo systemctl start sshd.service
```

Comment: Why would the SSH daemon ***on the local machine*** affect the user’s ability to connect to another machine?

Comment: That's a fair point, nonetheless it solved the problem.

Comment: correlation vs causation